# How to get a an object in list with min field value using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get an object from the list that has minimum price value.
I did it following way but not getting the item. I do not want to do ordering.

```
cOrderItem oItem = this.OrderItems
                .Where(p => p.CategoryID == catID && p.n_IsOfferApplied == false)
                .Min(p => p.OrderItemPrice).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try order by and fetch first element

```
cOrderItem oItem = this.OrderItems.
   Where(p => p.CategoryID == catID && p.n_IsOfferApplied == false).
   OrderBy(p => p.OrderItemPrice).FirstOrDefault()
```

---

this is kind of work around i dont wnat you to use but as you requested you dont want order by than

```
 var data = (from r in OrderItems
            where r.CategoryID == catID && r.n_IsOfferApplied == false
                   group r by r.CategoryID into g
                   select new { id = g.Key, data= g.Min(a=>a.OrderItemPrice) }).
                 FirstOrDefault();

 var cat =  from r in OrderItems
            join d in data data on d.id == r.CategoryID
            select r;
```

Note : solution is not tried by me and not recommended to use

Comment: From question: *"I do not want to do ordering."*

Comment: @L.B - yes i got that but i m not sure why ...because its easy way to do it

Comment: MinBy is easier and O(n).

Comment: if i will use order by will it make permanganate ordering to OrderItems..or it will be limited to this query only..

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet testing it could be faster than writing this comment.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - i dont this its going to affect actual collection..you can test it as LB said

Answer (score 1):

You have to match each element against the minimum value that is occuring in the collection.

```
cOrderItem oItem = this.OrderItems
            .Where(p => 
                       p.CategoryID == catID 
                       && p.n_IsOfferApplied == false

                       //Read as: "where the OrderItemPrice value is equal to the lowest occuring value in this.OrderItems
                       && p.OrderItemPrice == this.OrderItems.Min(q => q.OrderItemPrice))

            .FirstOrDefault();
```

In case you need multiple items (if they have the same OrderItemPrice), you can do the exact same query, but drop the `.FirstorDefault()` at the end.

Comment: A very inefficient way.

Answer (score 0):

`Min` doesn't return the item.It returns an integer or double result etc.If you want the item first get the min value then use it with where clause

```
var minValue = this.OrderItems.Min(p => p.OrderItemPrice);
cOrderItem oItem = this.OrderItems.Where(p => p.CategoryID == catID 
                                             && p.n_IsOfferApplied == false
                                             &&  p.OrderItemPrice == minValue)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use `OrderBy` it creates new, ordered copy of source sequence in memory (and enumerates source one more time). If you want to avoid this, you can use [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) MinBy (available from NuGet)

```
cOrderItem oItem = OrderItems
                .Where(p => p.CategoryID == catID && !p.n_IsOfferApplied)
                .MinBy(p => p.OrderItemPrice);
```

NOTE: it will throw exception if there is no matching items, so you can use your own extension to return default value if it is possible that no matches will be found:

```
    public static T MinBy<T, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> selector)
    {
        // throw if source or selector is null
        using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!iterator.MoveNext())
               return default(T);

            var min = iterator.Current;
            var minKey = selector(min);
            IComparer<TKey> comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                var current = iterator.Current;
                var currentKey = selector(current);
                if (comparer.Compare(currentKey, minKey) < 0)
                {
                    min = current;
                    minKey = currentKey;
                }
            }

            return min;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Just interesting - what's wrong with this solution? It does not use ordering and it fixes issue with empty sequence in default MinBy implementation